# Can I programmatically access / modify the navigation stack when NOT using a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I didn't use a UINavigationController, nor UITabController (more about that below*).  I have a sequence of 7 view controllers that the user walks thru to configure the app.

Now I want to be able to programmatically push and pop views on and off the navigation stack depending on what happens along the way.  Specifically I want to jump directly to a certain view controller but make it so that the unwind would include some views I have jumped over.  Every answer tells you to mess with the UINavigationController.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31193774/883354) only answers about viewing the stack in the debugger.

*Maybe I've burned myself by not using the UINavigationController. But every text book says that the UINavigationController is for hierarchical views. I was settings up a sequence of peer views.  So I thought I was following best practice by not using the UINavigationController, but honestly I'm starting to regret it.  However there must be a navigation stack somewhere because unwinding certainly brings you back to the previous view controller.

Comment: You can check my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

If I can understand your idea correctly, you really want to implement a hierarchical structure, but with dynamic items. And actually the stack is hierarchical structure, just every parent has only one child.

Going trough code ...

### Dirty Way

You will need UINavigationController:

```
    let shoudlRemoveIndex = 3
    let shouldAdd = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyCoolViewController")

    if var stack = navigationController?.viewControllers,
        let newVC = shouldAdd {
        stack.remove(at: shoudlRemoveIndex)
        stack.append(newVC)
        // or: stack.insert(newVC, at: desiredIndex)

        navigationController?.viewControllers = stack
    }
```

This should give you enough information how to control the stack.

if you want animations you can use this way:

```
    if let newVC = shouldAdd {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
    }

    if var stack = navigationController?.viewControllers {
        stack.remove(at: shoudlRemoveIndex)
        navigationController?.viewControllers = stack
    }
```

### Clean Way

Other approach may be segue and unwind segue. You can check how this works in this article: https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f

One unwindSegue on every ViewController and just call the right segue. This way you will have more clear structure and visually more understandable Storyboard.

---

The idea of the navigation controller content is to be a real stack, but in reality you can manipulate it as you need.
It's better to use already made working good component as UINavigationController, than implementing something custom-made and strange that has no guarantee that will work in future versions of iOS. One such way will be to try to instantiate viewControllers and get their views and replace current viewController view with the new one but keeping reference to the old ones ... way too trouble producing way :)

Comment: Sorry I have to down-vote this.  The whole premise for the question and reason this is challenging is that I don't have a UINavigationController.

Comment: No problem. I'll keep the answer for the people that already has taken your way and need a road sign where to go.